# Why does psql only works when I pass in a string?

Tags: postgresql, psql

This fails with `tlsv1 alert unknown ca`

```
psql -h localhost -p 4566 -d dev -U root --set=sslmode=disable
```

This works:

```
psql "port=4566 host=localhost user=root dbname=dev sslmode=disable"
```

Why? Why does one work when the other does not? Is the `--set` ignored?

Is this a bug or a feature?

Comment: Because per [psql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html): *" --set=assignment ... Perform a variable assignment, like the \set meta-command. ..."*. It does not change the ssl behavior for the connection itself and `\set sslmode=disable` has no meaning in `psql`: `\set sslmode=disable invalid variable name: "sslmode=disable"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The --set is not ignored, it just doesn't do anything meaningful.  It tells psql to set the **psql** variable named 'sslmode', but that variable is not in charge of anything.  If you could connect and you then ran `select :'sslmode';`, you find that it had indeed been set, but since it isn't in charge of anything this doesn't really matter much.

<s>The</s>A way to do this correctly, assuming you are using bash, is:

```
PGSSLMODE=disable psql -h localhost -p 4566 -d dev -U root
```

Answer (score 0):

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-connect.html#LIBPQ-PARAMKEYWORDS
https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html
The second one works. Because (sslmode=disable) is part of the connection string key words.

`psql --help` returns:

```
  -s, --single-step        single-step mode (confirm each query)
  -S, --single-line        single-line mode (end of line terminates SQL command)
```

also if you `psql --help | grep ssl`, there is zero result. which mean you cannot use simple use
`psql -h localhost -p 4566 -d dev -U root --sslmode=disable` .

jjanes's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74143785/15603477) works because: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-envars.html